# node.js 'not found' warnings

Tags: ubuntu, node.js

When I run configure, I'm seeing 'not found' warning messages for port.h, sys/event.h, and kqueue.

```
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for library dl                  : yes 
Checking for openssl                     : yes 
Checking for library util                : yes 
Checking for library rt                  : yes 
--- libeio ---
Checking for library pthread             : yes 
Checking for function pthread_create     : yes 
Checking for function pthread_atfork     : yes 
Checking for futimes(2)                  : yes 
Checking for readahead(2)                : yes 
Checking for fdatasync(2)                : yes 
Checking for pread(2) and pwrite(2)      : yes 
Checking for sendfile(2)                 : yes 
Checking for sync_file_range(2)          : yes 
--- libev ---
Checking for header sys/inotify.h        : yes 
Checking for function inotify_init       : yes 
Checking for header sys/epoll.h          : yes 
Checking for function epoll_ctl          : yes 
Checking for header port.h               : not found 
Checking for header poll.h               : yes 
Checking for function poll               : yes 
Checking for header sys/event.h          : not found 
Checking for header sys/queue.h          : yes 
Checking for function kqueue             : not found 
Checking for header sys/select.h         : yes 
Checking for function select             : yes 
Checking for header sys/eventfd.h        : yes 
Checking for function eventfd            : yes 
Checking for SYS_clock_gettime           : yes 
Checking for library rt                  : yes 
Checking for function clock_gettime      : yes 
Checking for function nanosleep          : yes 
Checking for function ceil               : yes 
Checking for fdatasync(2) with c++       : yes 
'configure' finished successfully (1.808s)
```

Do I need these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`configure` is used as part of the standard build process (`configure`, `make`, `make install`) to check for various dependencies for different systems.

The configure did complete successfully, so if `make` and `make install` works you should be fine unless you are missing features you need.

So the things missing are probably either optimizations or are not applicable to your system (For example, some of those headers might be only for OS X or BSD).